# Updating Salesforce Object via SSJS in Marketing Cloud

Tags: ssjs, mobileconnect, unsubscriber

I  would like to perform an update on the Lead Object in Salesforce as soon as the relative Marketing Cloud Subscriber perform the unsubscribe via Mobile SMS in Marketing Cloud. I tried using Ampscript and an automation Script using SSJS. 
Do you have about I could achieve?

Thanks,
Stefano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add AMPScript directly to the Unsubscribe Response SMS that updates the Lead Record using the function UpdateSingleSalesforceObject.

Comment: Hi Zeli, yes I tried, but it didn't work. I have a 320 char limits and it seems not able to read the ampscript.

Comment: Are you sure ? I remember doing this hack last year for one of my clients. If you have character limitation, try to put your AMPScript in a Content Block and then Invoke it with ContentBlockbyId function.

Comment: You are the man! I removed the first part of the script (the <> ones) and it seems to go. Now I need to understand how can I get the mobile Contact key (which is the LeadId in Salesforce)...

Comment: Your mobile contact key is your subscriber key ? Try using %%subscriberkey%% more info : https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/personalization_strings/strings/

Comment: Here is what I tried but it didn't work
%%[UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Lead',_subscriberkey,'et4ae5__HasOptedOutOfMobile__c', 'false')]%%

Comment: At first try to print the value of _subscriberkey and make sure that the ID exists as a Lead record in Salesforce.

Comment: It seems to be null...Don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

SubscriberKey isn't exposed in Mobile Connect. We usually create a 2nd version of it as an attribute to use for lookup functions. do you have any other variables to use for a lookup to expose the SubcriberKey?
This is the same across MobileConnect & MobilePush.

Comment: Hi! actually I've noticed that we are not able to get the contactId also, so we are trying to understand why. Do you have any Idea?

Comment: Neither ContactID or ContactKey are exposed as attributes, you need to use a mobile connect attribute to then lookup against